# List Item Reminder Emails

Tags: list, workflow, wss-3.0, reminder

We are creating a process that needs to be a staged process in our WSS 3.0 list. We have a staged process where certain teams need to come in after another team, so we have "then Wait for so and so to be Completed". We can send an email like this, but we want to be able to send reminder emails for each day the team didn't mark that they completed their part, since they're supposed to in 24 hours. Possibly even escalate with different email addresses on the second day.

Is there a way to do this without modifying code? We are attempting SharePoint migration right now and don't want to modify anything with code. We just want to create a workflow or something to complete this.

Thank you.

Edit: To add something to do this, we want to kind of incorporate an or statement or something of the like. For example, we want to halt the workflow until the team states they completed their part, OR after 24 hours send a reminder email, then 48 hours send another reminder email, etc. Kind of like a loop. If you wait for the field to be completed and 24 hours have past? Send a reminder, then loop back.

Comment: This would be feasible in 2013, but in 3.0 I think you're out of luck. You might be able to buy third-party to do the reminders (BoostSolutions may have 3.0/2007 support)

Comment: I figured as much. hopefully we upgrade soon. For now, I have pause for durations in there.

Comment: I have written workflows that run on edit, pause 24 hours, check conditions, and send a reminder. Then I reset a flag which "edits" the item, relaunching the workflow. But it's not reliable and if there are very many items in your list, it can bog down the workflow engine.

Comment: This is exactly what I did. I created pauses for durations and it seems to be doing what we need it to. Thank you!

Comment: Great. I'll add it as a solution so you can accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a workflow that runs on edit, pauses 24 hours, check conditions, and send a reminder. Then reset a flag which "edits" the item, relaunching the workflow. It's not the most reliable method, and you don't want to do this if you'll have large numbers of items this is running on. But with wss 3.0 you're fairly limited.